# Where to start searching when GraphicsCapturePicker only works after FolderPicker?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, interop

I would like to do the following in WPF based on .NET 4.8:

- One MainWindow.xaml including

  - a ScreenCaptureUserControl.xaml

    - More or less only a display user control.
  - a ActualUserControl.xaml

    - Gives the user several control possibilities. Not just for ScreenCaptureUserControl.

The MainWindow.xaml just wraps both user controls. The idea is to have them separate for better maintenance.

In this setup I have a button in ActualUserControl.xaml to start the screen capturing.
My idea was to forward the click information to the ScreenCaptureUserControl.xaml.

Excerpt from ActualUserControl.xaml

```
private async void StartScreenGrabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    // Working
    // await _mainWindow.StartPickerCaptureAsync(window);
    
    // Not working
    await _screenCaptureControl.StartPickerCaptureAsync(window);
}
```

Excerpt from ScreenCaptureUserControl.xaml

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("3E68D4BD-7135-4D10-8018-9FB6D9F33FA1")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComVisible(true)]
interface IInitializeWithWindow
{
    void Initialize(
        IntPtr hwnd);
}

public async Task StartPickerCaptureAsync(Window window)
{
    // Create a folder picker.
    var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();

    // Initialize the folder picker with the window handle (HWND).
    var interop = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)folderPicker;
    IntPtr intPtr = GetWindowHandle(window);
    interop.Initialize(intPtr);

    // Use the folder picker as usual.
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    // If the following line is commented out the GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync does not appear
    var folder = folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    
    var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
    interop = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)picker;
    interop.Initialize(intPtr);
    GraphicsCaptureItem item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();
    if (item != null)
    {
        sample.StartCaptureFromItem(item);
    }
}
```

When I tried this originally, it did not work: the GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync window did not work.

To find the issue, I tried if it works with the FolderPicker from this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/display-ui-objects#winui-3-with-c-also-wpfwinforms-with-net-6-or-later (I'm aware that it is .NET 6 or later, but that's why I adapted the code slightly).

To my surprise..

1. ... the FolderPicker worked without issues
2. ... the GraphicsCapturePicker works also if called after the FolderPicker

I nailed it down to following line:

```
    // If the following line is commented out the GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync does not appear
    var folder = folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

I tried debugging the issue and saw a difference in the output window during execution:
With the folderPicker the `Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0` is loaded.
Without the folderPicker it is not loaded.

As a workaround I tried to force loading this assembly by initializing an object from it:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.NamespaceResolveEventArgs args = new System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.NamespaceResolveEventArgs("hello", null);
```

This did force the assembly to load, but had no effect for my GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync.

At this point I would like to debug further, but I have no idea how or where.

What I also tried: Based on the origin of the call (StartScreenGrabButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)) I expect it to already run on a UI thread so that should not be the issue.
However, to ensure this I also tried running in within an `await _mainWindow.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`.